# How to make the Java code to call a String from a XML file(In Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, xml, string, android-studio

I have this code and I will like to make it multi language app. What I want is to use the Strings
from the Strings.xml file under the directory of values.

Let's say I have a `Toast`...

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WELCOME", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But I don't want to put the welcome in the java but to get it from the xml file, but How?

Answer (score 9):

Put `getString(R.string.welcome)` instead of "WELCOME".

Answer (score 5):

You have to use it like this:

```
getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.YOURSTRING);
```

Depending where in code, a simple

```
getString(R.string,ID);
```

could be enough.

Answer (score 2):

In the res/values folder there is a file called strings.xml put there the String

Example

```
<string name="welcome">Welcome</string>
```

and change the Toast to

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.welcome, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

now if you want to add more languages create libraries in the res folder named according to the language : **values-fr/** and place inside strings.xml

[Android Multi Language Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line above your current code snippet:

```
String data=userInput.getEditableText().toString();
```

Here, `userInput` is the id of your EditText tag in xml file.

And just change the original line of your code to:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You entered "+data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

String file

```
<string name="hi"> Hi  </string>
<string name="ten"> out of 10  </string>
<string name="youHaveScored"> you have Scored </string>
```

Java file

```
String finalScore = getString(R.string.hi) +name+ getString(R.string.youHaveScored)+score+ getString(R.string.ten);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),finalScore,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```